# JQuery: How to reduce selected node based on given offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using JQuery (also DOM API) to select the text node. Once I select the text node then I need to again reselect based on the count of character (offset). I am not sure how to do.

Sample Code:

```
var jCommentElm = jQuery("#345345"); //Select the original text
var finalSelectedComment = Not sure how to do?;          //Apply offset to select limited chars as per given count
finalSelectedComment .addClass("commentedtext"); //Apply CSS to highlight
```

**Edit:**
Following is sample marker which I am using to add comments. I have starting marker and offset of comment. I use starting marker to select the complete text after marker and now i want to reduce my selection based on offset.

```
<p > This is sample text. Few <?comment_marker 4?>chars may be selected together and mark as comment</p>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide more context on what you are trying to do? Also show the markup

Comment: I am trying to highlight the text based on initial marker and number of next chars count given.

Comment: I have also added this details in original query.

Comment: very hard to make any sense out of this fragmented question. No idea what `<?comment_marker?>` is, or where it comes from. No offset, or count shown anywhere in code other than in comment. Not clear at all what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGHad/1/)):

HTML:

```
<p>This is sample text. Few <span data-chars="4"></span>chars may be selected together and mark as comment</p>
```

CSS:

```
.hi {
    background: yellow;    
}
```

jQuery:

```
selectText('p');

function selectText(el) {
    var el = $(el),
        charEl = el.children("span[data-chars]"),
        chars = parseInt(charEl.attr('data-chars')), //4
        html = el.html(),
        regex = /\<span data-chars=\"\d+\"\>\<\/span\>/gi,
        index = html.search(regex),
        newStr = html.replace(regex,''),
        beg = newStr.substr(0,index),
        mid = newStr.substr(index,chars),
        end = newStr.substr(index + chars);

    el.html(beg + '<span class="hi">'+mid+'</span>' + end);

}
```

1. This will look for an empty SPAN (that acts as a 'marker') with the HTML5 data-* element of however many characters you want to highlight, starting after that SPAN.
2. It will then cache the index of the marker, remove the marker, chop the original string into a beginning portion up to the marker index, a portion from the marker index plus however many characters you want to select, and then an ending portion.
3. These three portions are then reassembled back into your parent element's innerHTML, with the middle portion being wrapped by a different SPAN with a class of 'hi' (short for 'highlight'), which has a background-color property of 'yellow' (or whatever color you would prefer).

*CONS*
o   Whitespace counts as a character
o   Might be a bit finicky to go back and then remove $('.hi')